# One Table is not being created other is being created

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table, insert-into

I am working on creating table in to my database with mysql and here is my code:

```
mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review` (
            `clients_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `client_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `rating` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `proj_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
            `proj_desc` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `photoname` text NOT NULL,
            `companyname` text NOT NULL,
            `feedback` text NOT NULL,
            `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `emailid` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `customratings` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `photo_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `citation` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `date_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `rating_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            PRIMARY KEY (`clients_id`),
            FULLTEXT KEY `feedback` (`feedback`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=1") or mysqli_error($link);
```

But this is not reflecting into my database ? Why were I may be going wrong ?

but I tried creating other table with the following code

```
mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setting` (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            `script_url` text NOT NULL,
            `date` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `rateing` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `photo` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `dateformat` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `page_limit` int(4) NOT NULL,
            `proj_desc` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `companyname` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
            `text_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `citation_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `bg_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `border_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `ratingsformat` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `rating` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `customratings` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `speed` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `pagination` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `version` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `global_option` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
        ") or mysqli_error($link);
```

it is being created correctly  and both the tables are in the same file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: No. You need to create the table first.

Comment: The mysql syntax is now ok (after edit) - so if there is a problem, check PHP side, or the connection.

Comment: @ringø I am creating these tables in the same single  php file while one table  is being created and other table is not being created. What could be the problem?

Comment: If I have remove DEFAULT ' ' in review ,the table is being created. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me but I don't know how?

I just removed DEFAULT '' present while creating review table and table just got created
Here is edited code

```
mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review` (
            `clients_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `client_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
            `rating` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
            `proj_date` date NOT NULL,
            `proj_desc` text NOT NULL,
            `photoname` text NOT NULL,
            `companyname` text NOT NULL,
            `feedback` text NOT NULL,
            `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
            `emailid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `customratings` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `photo_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `citation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `date_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `rating_option` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`clients_id`),
            FULLTEXT KEY `feedback` (`feedback`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=1") or mysqli_error($link);
```

Comment: This leads me to 1364 mysql error while inserting data

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot create table using an insert statement.

There are four types of SQL statements:

1. DML (DATA MANIPULATION LANGUAGE)
2. DDL (DATA DEFINITION LANGUAGE)
3. DCL (DATA CONTROL LANGUAGE)
4. TCL (TRANSACTION CONTROL LANGUAGE)

DML is your SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements...
DDL is you your CREATE, ALTER and DROP statements.

[See more info about types of SQL statements](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/types-of-sql-statements-with-example)

In order to insert data in your table, first you need to create it.

[How to create sql table from php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)

Comment: Edited my question now have a look at it

Comment: @Nawaz, this is a new/different question now, I think it would be best to ask a separate question for this. By changing the question, all the answers become irrelevant. Also if you are getting any error message, could you please include them.

Answer (score 0):

No. "INSERT INTO" used to insert the data to existing table only.You should create the table with respective column before try to insert the values.

Or you can check the table exist or not before going insert."If exists" u can insert the value else just create and insert the values.